# Problem adding view to the end of my UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that contains a bunch of views:

```
for(NSDictionary* deal in deals)
    {
        [items addObject:deal];

        DealViewController *dvc = [[DealViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DealViewController" bundle:nil];
        [dvc setNavigationController:[self navigationController]];
        UIView *dealView = [dvc view];
        [dealViewControllers addObject:dvc];

        //setup scrollView
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * i; 
        NSLog(@"Frame origin: %f", frame.origin.x);
        [dealView setFrame:frame];
        [scrollView addSubview:dealView];
        i++;
        [dvc displayDeal:deal];
    }
```

I want to add a view to the very end of the scrollview as follows:

```
SignUpViewController* signUpView = [[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
[scrollView insertSubview:signUpView.view atIndex:[items count]];
```

The signUpView appears at the beginning of the UIScrollView. How can I add it to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * i;
[signUpView setFrame:frame];
```

You didn't tell it where to draw.

Answer (score 0):

Try With

```
[scrollView insertSubview:signUpView.view atIndex:[items count] - 1];
```

Let me know if you struggle with issue

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: Plz  Check the frame of signUpView ?